# How to zip a create-react-app project so it runs using "npm install" / "npm start"?

Tags: npm

I have created an npm project using "npx create-react-app my-app" as described [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started), and edited the resulting App.js (only this file).  Now I need to zip and email the app, in source code form (not optimized form), so that it can be unzipped and run using "npm install" and "npm start".

The project contains a very large local "node_modules" folder, so I don't want to include this, I expect the purpose of the recipient running "npm install" is to reinstall all that stuff. However, if I create a zip containing only "package.json", "src", and "public", the "npm install" command takes a very long time and installs far more than was included in the first place.  I'm not sure this is normal.  If I also include "package-lock.json", "npm install" runs more quickly.

**What is the correct way to zip a npm project, so that it can be unzipped and run using "npm install" and "npm start" by the recipient?**

I don't know how to use npm (I've had it installed for around 2 hours), so assuming zero knowledge would be ideal.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to delete the node_modules folder from the project and also the "package-lock.json" file.
Then zip it.
Email it.
Your receiver will download, unzip and run "npm install" to have them again back.